# Error al intentar crear usuario desde el admin en django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

estoy intentando crear un usuario pero estoy teniendo el siguiente error

**IntegrityError at /admin/auth/user/add/
llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «userprofile_profile_user_id_f37c6bb1_uniq»
DETAIL:  Ya existe la llave (user_id)=(14).**

Tengo el models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_in_charge = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='users', verbose_name='Ejecutivo a Cargo', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField('Telefono de Contacto', max_length=12, blank=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(default='default-avatar.png', upload_to='users/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

en el admin.py tengo el stackedinline pero no me esta funcionando

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline): 
    model = Profile 
    fk_name = 'user'
    fields = ('user_in_charge', 'phone_number',)


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    list_display = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'get_phone', 'get_user_in_charge',)
    list_select_related = True 
    inlines = [ UserProfileInline, ] 
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'groups')
    ordering = ['id']
    readonly_fields = [
        'last_login',
        'date_joined',
    ]

    def get_user_in_charge(self, obj):
        return obj.profile.user_in_charge

    get_user_in_charge.admin_order_field = 'Ejecutivo a Cargo'
    get_user_in_charge.short_description = 'Ejecutivo a Cargo'

    def get_phone(self, obj):
        return obj.profile.phone_number

    get_phone.admin_order_field = 'Telefono de Contacto'
    get_phone.short_description = 'Telefono de Contacto'


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

si comento el UserProfileInline junto con el useradmin funciona correctamente la creación del usuario, pero no logro hacerlo andar con el stackedinline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero que nada (pep8) tenés dos espacios en
user = models.OneToOneField(User,<  >on_delete=models.CASCADE) ;)

Pregunta, no es mejor unificar el profile en el userAbstract que creaste? así tendrías todo en el mismo modelo y no tendrías problemas de este tipo.

Luego el model User que estás ocupando para hacer oneToOne en profile, lo estás importando de tus modelos de User? porque luego estás ocupando settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL para hacer otra relación. Porqué no intentás generar la relación con el mismo modelo, o la misma sintaxis?

Comment: Gracias NIcolas, tenes razón voy a optar por usar Pep8 y hacer un solo usuario que herede de AbstractUser, porque yo al modificar el User, no deberia usar el User por defecto !!